# Command design pattern with friend class in C++

Tags: c++, encapsulation, friend, command-pattern

The situation: I have to handle and take action on various commands, which can be encapsulated in the command design pattern. So right now I have

```
class Command {
    virtual void applyCommand(IFoo& foo) = 0;
    virtual ~Command() = default;
};
```

and of course I inherit this interface into my individual command classes.

However now, I realize that just passing `IFoo` isn't enough. I want to be able to access private data members in my `ConcreteFoo` class. I justify this break in encapsulation because when it comes down to it, all these objects are basically just helper functions for my `ConcreteFoo` class. I'm fine with them being strongly coupled because one way or the other, I have to write these methods, and doing the CDP makes it more readable.

So, I change my class to

```
class Command {
    virtual void applyCommand(ConcreteFoo& foo) = 0;
    virtual ~Command() = default;
};
```

and in my ConcreteFoo class I declare

```
friend class Command;
```

However, **friendship apparently is not inherited** into the subclasses of Command, the classes that actually do the work. So I can't actually get access to the data I need.

My current thoughts on solving this are:

1.) Take the L and just handle this without the CDP

- possible, but I don't really want to take this route if I can avoid it

2.) Make data members in ConcreteFoo public

- no

3.) Make data members in ConcreteFoo protected, and somehow make Command a subclass of ConcreteFoo

- no

4.) Manually declare each Command subclass a friend, so like

```
friend class CommandA;
friend class CommandB;
friend class CommandC;
friend class CommandD;
...
```

- decent, but might not scale well. on the plus side, if I forget to friend, it should fail at compile time

None of these options are particularly appealing to me. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: The command patter is supposed to **encapsulate** the request, why do you want to expose its private members?

Answer (score 2):

You’re basically working on visitor pattern (your Command class is a visitor to Foo classes).

One way to go around this, you might have a public interface of Command (`applyCommand` non-virtual) and virtual implementation(s) (`applyCommandImpl` virtual). You can make `Command` itself a friend and `Command::applyCommand` could extract the necessary data and pass it to the particular `applyCommandImpl`.

Normally, you’d simply extract the necessary parameters and pass those. However, if you really want to access all members, then you might do this: have the members of Foo in a struct (say, `Foo1DO`, as in data object) and inherit from it privately to have `Foo1`. Then you can have a simple getter to reach `Foo1DO` from `Foo1` in `applyCommand`.